How can I inline parameters in EFCore?
Then track performance of query you can invoke ToQueryString method. If you have a lot of parameters in query it just add @p1, @p2, etc. What to do if you want inline it?

There are several different ways. The degree of their applicability depends on the DBMS used, so specify it. For example, you can use an array in PostgreSQL or a TVP in Sql Server. Also we can use JSON and functions like OPENJSON in Sql Server or JSON_EACH in SQLite. We can also create a temporary table, fill in the data and then JOIN it to the query.

Inline... only for the query string? You probably don't want to inline parameters for query execution, do you?

@GertArnold, looks like bad prepared Q&A. OP is trying to show how to visualise complex query without parameters for probably Copy/Paste to SQL Analyser or other tool.

You can just use this expression visitor for inline parameters:
public class ParameterReplacer : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression is ConstantExpression constantExpression)
        {
            var container = constantExpression.Value;
            var member = node.Member;

            if (member is System.Reflection.FieldInfo field)
            {
                var value = field.GetValue(container);
                if (value is string or not IEnumerable)
                {
                    return Expression.Constant(value, field.FieldType);
                }
            }
            else if (member is System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property)
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(container);
                if (value is string or not IEnumerable)
                {
                    return Expression.Constant(value, property.PropertyType);
                }
            }
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> ReplaceParamToConst<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        var replacer = new ParameterReplacer();
        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(replacer.Visit(query.Expression));
    }
}


Usage: ParameterReplacer.ReplaceParamToConst(query).ToQueryString();
